# Laravel ajax output json error messages

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, laravel

Hi I'm using Laravel and jQuery Ajax to submit a contact form. This works perfectly and I can catch the success message easily as its a string. But my error message is being passed as an array, so I guess it works differently as the error messages aren't been output. But I can see in my console that it is been passed back as so:

```
errors: {name: ["The name field is required."], email: ["The email field is required."],…}
email: ["The email field is required."]
message: ["The message field is required."]
name: ["The name field is required."]
success: false
```

I'm trying to append these error messages as so into my html:

```
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, json, errors) {
                $( "#errors" ).append(json.message );

          }
```

and my controller passes this to the ajax as so:

```
 return Response::json(array('success' => false,
                        'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
```

However this is having no effect. Am I missing something? My code is below. Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

```
public function getContactUsForm()
        {

            if(Request::ajax()){

                    $data = Input::all();
                    $rules = array(
                                    'name' => 'required',
                                    'email' => 'required',
                                    'message' => 'required');
                        // catch validation and pass back json reponse if not filled in correctly.
                     $validator = Validator::make ($data, $rules);
                        if ($validator -> passes()){
                            //Send email using Laravel send function
                            Mail::send('emails.contactform', $data, function($message) use ($data)
                            {
                                $message->from(Config::get('mail.from')['address'], Config::get('mail.from')['name']);
                                   $message->to('mail@gmail.com', 'Test')->subject(' Contact Form');

                            });  
                             return Response::json(array(
                                'success' => true,
                                'message' => 'Thank you, your message has been sent.'

                            )); 
                        } // end if start else
                            else
                            {
                                return Response::json(array(
                                    'success' => false,
                                    'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()

                                ));
                            }

                }
                else {
                    return 'NOT AN AJAX RESPONSE...';
                }

        }
```

and my ajax call is below:

```
$('#submit-contact').on('submit', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault(); 

  var name = $('#name').val();
  var message = $('#message').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();

  $.ajax({
         url: '/contact_request',
         headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        data: {name:name, message:message, email:email},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (json) {
          // clear inputs
            $('#name,#message,#email').val('');
            // append success message
            $( "#success" ).append(json.message );

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, json) {
            $( "#errors" ).append(json.errors );

      }
    });
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the `json.errors` object properties to output each error message value:

```
error: function (jqXHR, json) {
    for (var error in json.errors) {
        $('#errors').append(json.errors[error] + '<br>');
    }
}
```

Comment: ```json.errors[error]``` is an array instead of a string?